# unable to open ubuntu in Oracle VM Virtual box

Tags: server, virtualbox, cpu

When i start the Ubuntu in Oracle VM Virtual box, it throws following error.

```
This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU,but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot- Please use a kernel, appropriate to your CPU.
```

Kindly lend your help to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is self-explanatory. You have configured the CPU of the virtualbox guest as 32 bit while you are trying to install a 64-bit Ubuntu.

To solve this issue either install the 32-bit version of Ubuntu or configure the virtualbox to set the CPU of the guest as 64 bit.

Note that Ubuntu server editions do not come with a 32 bit version now-a-days so if you are trying to install the server edition you should better configure the virtualbox accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the response.. Should i have to download new version or can i update it by any means ?

Comment: @Reshma If you are going to install desktop version then download the 32 bit version from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) or you need to configure the virtualbox guest machine to have a 64 bit CPU.

Comment: please , could you recommend any link to get the VM virtual box for 64 bit cpu

Comment: @Reshma Is your host machine 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: its 64 bit machine

Comment: @Reshma https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/how_to_configure_a_64